# What to do? Multiple PATCH request or one Bulk request?

Tags: soql, javascript, rest-api, browser

I have an operation which requires an update for every eligible record in an object (approx. 30 records at most in a single operation) via REST API. I plan to fire multiple PATCH request to do so but it seems cumbersome on second thought so I plan to use Bulk API.
The thing is, Bulk API is for thousands of concurrent requests that using it for less than forty requests seems like an overkill.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using the Bulk API for this purpose; it's too limited to waste your Bulk API calls on a mere 40 records. Instead, you can use the [Composite Resource API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm), which allows you to batch up to 25 calls in to a single request.

Comment: Wow. I've just heard that API. I'll check it out ASAP (y)